# Destruction of each other in c++ shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

everyone. I find a problem in c++ deconstruction. I will show you my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class B;

class A{
public:
    typedef shared_ptr<A> Ptr;

    shared_ptr<B> b;

    int index;

    A(const shared_ptr<B>& b_, int index_):b(b_), index(index_){}

    ~A(){cout << "A is deleted." << endl;
         cout << "A id is " << index << endl;}



};

class B{
public:
    typedef shared_ptr<B> Ptr;

    vector<A::Ptr> all_a;

    void addA(){
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            auto a = make_shared<A>(Ptr(this), i);

            all_a.push_back(a);
        }

    }

    int index;

    B(int index_):index(index_){

    }

    ~B(){
        cout << "B is deleted." << endl;
        cout << "B id is " << index << endl;
    }


};



int main(){

    B::Ptr b = make_shared<B>(5);

    b->addA();

    return 0;
}
```

A part of results is  is

```
... 
B is deleted.
B id is 5
A is deleted.
A id is 8
B is deleted.
B id is 5
A is deleted.
A id is 9
B is deleted.
B id is 5
double free or corruption (out)
[1]    29094 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

What is it happened with my code, how can i debug this problem.
I thought the shared_ptr has some bug in this case.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what are you trying to achieve, but most likely your error is somewhere around `Ptr(this)`. Take a look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Answer (score 8):

There's one problem at play and another that'll pop up when you fix it.

## Part 1: `shared_ptr`s that don't share

So, the reason you see a lot of destructor calls for the same `B` object and crash with a double-free error is this line:

```
auto a = make_shared<A>(Ptr(this), i);
```

In particular, `Ptr(this)` makes a `shared_ptr<B>` from `this` that stands alone -- it cannot know that there are other `shared_ptr`s somewhere else that feel responsible for the same object, it has its own reference count, and it'll believe that no one else is using the object it points to when that goes to zero. For all intents and purposes, it behaves like a `unique_ptr` because it never shares its reference count with another `shared_ptr` (except temporaries).

Unfortunately, you don't know a `shared_ptr` that manages the object you're working on inside the member function. Fortunately, there's something in the standard library to help with that: `std::enable_shared_from_this` It works like this:

```
class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {

// ...

   auto a = make_shared<A>(shared_from_this(), i);
```

Note that if you do this, the code expects that `B` will only ever be manged by `shared_ptr`s. Although, really, it already does that, so that's okay.

## Part 2: Round and round we go -- cyclic reference counts

Now, once you put that into your program, it'll not crash anymore. It'll also not print anything, as if nothing were ever deleted. What gives?

In fact, nothing is ever deleted, and the reason is that as far as all those `shared_ptr`s are concerned, their objects never go out of use. We've stumbled upon the main reason that reference-counting does not a full garbage collector make.

Your `B` object knows 10 `A` objects, but I'll consider only one of them -- it's just the thing I'm about to show 10 times. They have `shared_ptr`s to each other, and there are however many external `shared_ptr` that keep them alive as long as they are needed. Once all those external references are gone, you expect them to be deleted, but consider what the situation at that point looks like:

```
+-----+   shared_ptr<A>   +-----+
|     | ----------------> |     |
|  b  |                   |  a  |
|     | <---------------- |     |
+-----+   shared_ptr<B>   +-----+
```

`b` has a `shared_ptr` to `a`, so `a` has a reference count of 1. `a` has a `shared_ptr` to `b`, so `b` has a reference count of 1. We're caught in a catch-22: `a` is in use because `b` is use, and `b` is in use because `a` is in use, so neither is ever deleted.

When working with `shared_ptr`s, this kind of setup absolutely has to be avoided, and that's why `weak_ptr` exists. I have to guess which way you want the ownership mechanics to go, but for example you could have non-owning references from the `A` to the `B` objects like so:

```
class A{
    // ...
    weak_ptr<B> b;
```

and in `B`:

```
void addA(){
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      auto a = make_shared<A>(weak_from_this(), i);
      all_a.push_back(a);
    }
}
```

Then the objects in `all_a` will not keep the `B` object that owns them alive. To use it, you would write

```
std::shared_ptr<B> b2 = b.lock();
```

to have a `shared_ptr` that keeps it alive while you're working with it.

Comment: yes, you are true, i have learned weak_ptr but never used it, in this case, it is awesome. Because in this case, i only want to indicate the B's owner, so it also can change shared_ptr to normal pointer B*. And fortunately B and A can be deconstructed correctly, thank for your answer, it's most clearest and wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `shared_ptr<B>(this)` twice, you do not get 2 `shared_ptr` which manage `this` successfully.  You get 2 `shared_ptr` with separate control blocks each of which thinks they are the only manager of `this` .  Inevitably this will lead to a double delete or worse.

One way to solve this problem is to use `shared_from_this()` instead of `this`; [see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) for example.

Comment: yes, your method works better, and when I suffered from this problem, i find another method to solve it. I also this this problem will appear when mixed shared_ptr and normal pointer. I change A's constructor to A(B* b_, int index_):b(b_), index(index_){}, this will work too.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly noted in the C++ [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

The ownership of an object can only be shared with another shared_ptr by copy constructing or copy assigning its value to another shared_ptr. Constructing a new shared_ptr using the raw underlying pointer owned by another shared_ptr leads to undefined behavior.

I remember the old saying: if everything fails read the instruction first.

You also cannot mix plain pointer and shared_ptr in your code. You may be holding on a plain pointer that has already been freed by the shared_ptr using the plain pointe.